# how to get max value form arrat of object acc. to different -different key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to find max marks form an array of the object which has some same key-value pair

```
var arr = [
  {id:1, prog:'A', marks:90 },  
  {id:1 ,prog:'A', marks:89 },
  {id:2, prog:'A', marks:94 },
  {id:3, prog:'B', marks:91 },
  {id:4, prog:'B' ,marks:34},
  {id:5, prog:'B', marks:56 },
  {id:6, prog:'C', marks:50},
  {id:7, prog:'C', marks:99 }
]
```

this is my array I want the output like 
max marks from each program

```
var outputArr = [
  {id:2, prog:'A', marks:94},
  {id:3, prog:'B', marks:91 },
  {id:7 , prog:'C', marks:99 }
]
```

Comment: what if the max value is the same? what have you tried?

Comment: What in case of more than one object with same values of `prog` and `marks`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking so that your answer would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for guide me. - eibersji

Comment: @NinaScholz when the value of the mark will same then I will add that  object in my output array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom function below.

```
function groupByMax(arr, groupKey, maxKey) {
  const grouped = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (acc[groupKey] && acc[groupKey][maxKey] < item[maxKey]) {
      acc[groupKey] = item;
    } else if (!acc[groupKey]) {
      acc[groupKey] = item;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(grouped);
};

console.log(groupByMax(yourArray, 'prog', 'marks'));
```

Comment: no need to sort. just pick the max value.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Yes true sorting is not required, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let tmp= {}; // here objects will be grouped by prog

arr.forEach(o => tmp[o.prog] = (tmp[o.prog] || []).concat(o) )

let r = Object.keys(tmp).map(k => tmp[k].reduce((a,b) => a.marks>b.marks ? a:b))
```

```js
let arr = [
  {id:1, prog:'A', marks:90 },
  {id:1 ,prog:'A', marks:89 },
  {id:2, prog:'A', marks:94 },
  {id:3, prog:'B', marks:91 },
  {id:4,prog:'B' ,marks:34},
  {id:5, prog:'B', marks:56 },
  {id:6, prog:'C', marks:50},
  {id:7 , prog:'C', marks:99 }
];

let tmp= {};

arr.forEach(o => tmp[o.prog] = (tmp[o.prog] || []).concat(o) )

let r = Object.keys(tmp).map(k => tmp[k].reduce((a,b)=>a.marks>b.marks?a:b))

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```